# Splitting an STL list based on a condition

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, vector, stl

I have an std::list which looks as follows (the x marks indicate some number less than 500)

```
x,x,x,x,503,x,x,x,510,x,x,x,502,x,x,x,x,x,x,600 - std::list<int> originallist
```

I am looking to split the list into a vector of lists `std::vector<std::list<int> >` as follows

```
1st element of vector: x,x,x,x,503
2nd element of vector: x,x,x,510
...
...
last element of vector: x,x,x,x,x,x,600
```

The code I have now is as follows:

```
list<int> templist; vector<list<int> > v;
for(list<int>::iterator lit=originallist.begin(); lit!=oriniallist.end(); ++lit) {
    if (*lit > 500) {
        templist.push_back(*lit);v.push_back(templist); templist.clear(); continue;
    }
    templist.push_back(*lit);
}
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve the above task in c++ without using templist. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Lilshieste I did it in the most naive way - iterated through the original list, at the same time maintaining a temporary list. If I hit a number greater than 500, I push_back the temporary list to the vector and clear its contents. I wanted to know if I can do this without creating a temporary list.

Comment: Probably can't go wrong with boost::algorithm::find_all.

Comment: Can you share any code? It might help in keeping answers relevant to your task-at-hand. (And we might be able to help you tweak your existing approach.)

Comment: Do you need the original list to remain unchanged? If not, you could use [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) to cheaply chop off segments into the desired sublists.

Comment: @Blastfurnace The original list can change.

Comment: Splicing to a new list is unfortunately not very efficient with `std::list` (linear complexity). It's faster with a `std::forward_list` or with a different implementation of `std::list` (wasn't libstdc++'s implementation noncompliant in this respect?).

Comment: Must you use `std::list`?  It is extremely rare it is a good container for a problem.  Oh, and C++11 supoort?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I have to use std::list, I require it some place else. I was looking for a non c++11 solution.

Comment: @Yakk Please post an answer, I want to upvote something.

Comment: @Yakk Well not *that* bad. But OP wants performance, and IMO they're all *not* really great in this respect.

Comment: Your existing attempt is fine TBH . You could simplify it slightly by putting `templist.push_back(*lit);` before the `if` instead of having it duplicated in each case. Using `vector::reserve` could buy you some nanoseconds if it's a large list, if you had a good idea of how much you need to reserve.

Comment: Instead of `v.push_back(templist); templist.clear();` you could push back an empty list and then quickly `swap` its guts with `templist` to avoid coping the list contents all over again. So something like `v.push_back(list<int>()); v.back().swap(templist);`. This will leave `templist` empty and ready to be refilled.

Answer (score 5):

While this solution does use a temporary `std::list`, it allocates no list node elements, and does exactly 1 memory allocation in the C++03 case (the C++11 case does a logarithmic number of memory allocations on the size of the return value)

This is a C++03 solution.  A C++11 solution can do this in one pass.

```
bool big_as_500( int x ) {return x>=500;}

std::vector< std::list< int > > do_stuff( std::list<int>& original_list ) {
  // we have to do this, because resizing the return value involves lots of allocations
  // and stuff in C++03, so make sure we get the size right by precalculating it:
  std::size_t count = std::count_if( originallist.begin(), originallist.end(), big_as_500 );
  std::vector< std::list< int > > result;
  result.reserve(count+1); 

  typedef std::list<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;
  std::list< int > current;
  for(const_iterator it= originallist.begin(); it!=originallist.end();/*nothing*/) {
    ++it; // about to invalidate it! (or move lists)
    current.splice( current.end(), originallist, originallist.begin() ); // O(1) no memory allocation
    if (big_as_500(current.back())) {
      result.push_back( std::list<int>() );
      current.swap( result.back() );
    }
  }
  // original problem does not specify what to do if the original list does not end
  // with an element "big_as_500", so I'll just drop them
  return result; // rely on NRVO to eliminate the copy here, if your compiler does not
  // support it, take result as a reference parameter.
}
```

A C++11 solution:

```
std::vector< std::list< int > > do_stuff( std::list<int>& original_list ) {
  std::vector< std::list< int > > result;

  typedef std::list<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;
  std::list< int > current;
  for(const_iterator it= originallist.begin(); it!=originallist.end();/*nothing*/) {
    ++it;// about to become invalid/in wrong list
    current.splice( current.end(), originallist, originallist.begin() ); // O(1) no memory allocation
    if (current.back() >= 500) {
      result.emplace_back( std::move(current) );
    }
  }
  // original problem does not specify what to do if the original list does not end
  // with an element "big_as_500", so I'll just drop them
  return result; // will NRVO, or move, so no worries
}
```

in C++11, resizes are relatively cheap, so we are good.

Now, we could get really fancy in C++03 and emulate what C++11 does and do it all in one pass.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void efficient_grow_by_1( std::vector<T,A>& make_one_bigger ) {
  if (make_one_bigger.size()+1 > make_one_bigger.capacity() )
  {
    std::vector<T, A> swap_vec;
    swap_vec.reserve( (make_one_bigger.size()+1)*5/3 );
    for (std::vector<T, A>::iterator it = make_one_bigger.begin(); it != make_one_bigger.end(); ++it ) {
      using std::swap;
      swap_vec.push_back();
      std::swap( *it, swap_vec.back() );
    }
    swap_vec.swap( make_one_bigger );
  }
  make_one_bigger.push_back();
}
void do_stuff( std::list<int>& original_list, std::vector< std::list< int > >& result ) {
  typedef std::list<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;
  std::list< int > current;
  for(const_iterator it= originallist.begin(); it!=originallist.end();) {
    ++it;
    current.splice( current.end(), originallist, originallist.begin() ); // O(1) no memory allocation
    if (current.back()>=500) {
      efficient_grow_by_1(result);
      current.swap( result.back() );
    }
  }
  // original problem does not specify what to do if the original list does not end
  // with an element "big_as_500", so I'll just drop them
}
```

which is rather insane, so I'd advise upgrading your compiler.

The trick here is that we populate the 'temporary' list with a single-element-at-a-time `splice`.  Because (most? many?) implementations of `std::list::splice` end up having to walk over the elements to count them (it is required in C++11, and common in C++03), doing it one at a time as we determine which elements we want to put into the next chunk is reasonably efficient.  Each node comes directly from the input list, and is collected into the temporary list (no memory allocations).

Once we have built up this list, we directly `swap` it into the output `vector` of `list`s.  This avoids any memory allocations, other than that which is required to hold the (relatively small) base data of the `list`.

In C++03, we either do a two-pass solution and pre calculate how big the output `std::vector` is, or we emulate C++11 `move` efficiency with careful growth and `swap` mechanics on the contained `list`s.  It is possible that your `std` library implementation fakes this already, but I am unsure how common `swap`-`resize` optimization was in the old libraries.

Keeping things down to a single pass is probably worth the logarithmic number of allocations that the 2nd C++03 and C++11 solutions use: walking a `std::list` is an exercise in cache misses.

Comment: As an aside, I would advise against using `std::list` as a general rule.  Especially in C++11 where `std::vector` resizes are much cheaper (thanks to `move` support).

Comment: (I would replace the `const_iterator it= originallist.begin()` in C++11 with `auto it = originallist.begin()`, then you can get rid of the `typedef`.) For different allocators, I'm not sure if moving a list empties the source list, so my advice to use move instead of swap might not have been the best.

Answer (score 1):

### Third version

This version uses `std::list::splice` and moves iterator till `delim`iter is found or `end()` reached.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::list<int> > & split( std::list<int>  v,
                   int delim, std::vector< std::list<int> >& elems) {

    auto it = v.begin();

    while ( it != v.end()) {
        std::list<int> l;

        while ( it != v.end() && *it < delim) {
            ++it;
        }

        if( it != v.end()) {
            l.splice( l.begin(), v, v.begin(), ++it);
            it = v.begin();
        } else {
            l.splice( l.begin(), v, v.begin(), it);
        }

        elems.push_back( l);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector< std::list<int> > split( const std::list<int>  &v, int delim) {
    std::vector< std::list<int> > elems;
    split( v, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {

    std::list<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 503, 5, 6, 502, 7, 510, 3, 500, 6, 7};
    std::vector< std::list<int> > vl;
    vl = split( v, 500);

    int i = 0;
    while( i < vl.size()) {
        std::list<int>::const_iterator it = vl[ i].begin();
        while( it !=  vl[ i].end())
            std::cout << *it++;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/VRpGft

prints:

123503

56502

7510

3500

67

### First version

This version uses `std::list::splice`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::list<int> > & split( std::list<int>  v,
                   int delim, std::vector< std::list<int> >& elems) {

    auto it = v.begin();

    while ( it != v.end()) {
        std::list<int> l;
        auto it3 = l.begin();
        while ( it != v.end() && *it < delim) {
            l.splice( it3, v, it);
            it = v.begin();
        }
        if( it != v.end()) {
            l.splice( it3, v, it);
            it = v.begin();
        }
        elems.push_back( l);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector< std::list<int> > split( const std::list<int>  &v, int delim) {
    std::vector< std::list<int> > elems;
    split( v, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {

    std::list<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 503, 5, 6, 502, 7, 510, 3, 500, 5, 9};
    std::vector< std::list<int> > vl;
    vl = split( v, 500);

    int i = 0;
    while( i < vl.size()) {
        std::list<int>::const_iterator it = vl[ i].begin();
        while( it !=  vl[ i].end())
            std::cout << *it++;
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

prints:

123503565027510350059

http://ideone.com/1xMehy

### Second version

This is simplified version that doesn't use `std::list::splice` function. This function puts elements before the iterator so the loop would have to be slightly changed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::list<int> > & split( const std::list<int>  & v,
                   int delim, std::vector< std::list<int> >& elems) {

    std::list<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();

    while ( it != v.end()) {

        std::list<int> l;
        while ( it != v.end() && *it < delim) {
            l.push_back( *it++);
        }

        if( it != v.end()) l.push_back( *it++);
        elems.push_back( l);
    }

    return elems;
}


std::vector< std::list<int> > split( const std::list<int>  &v, int delim) {
    std::vector< std::list<int> > elems;
    split( v, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {

    std::list<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 503, 5, 6, 502, 7, 510, 3, 500, 5, 9};
    std::vector< std::list<int> > vl;
    vl = split( v, 500);

    int i = 0;
    while( i < vl.size()) {

        std::list<int>::const_iterator it = vl[ i].begin();

        while( it !=  vl[ i].end())
            std::cout << *it++;

        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

prints:

123503565027510350059

http://ideone.com/MBmlLE

Comment: OP has a `std::list` at the beginning, not a `std::vector`.

Comment: OP starts with *"I have an std::list which looks as follows"*

Comment: @dyp OK, we have a list

Comment: Now you can make it more efficient by splicing instead of copying (`push_back`).

Comment: splice works by putting befor iterator. The elements are inserted before the element pointed to by iterator. Could be used but this is simplified version.

Comment: I think you can use `l.end()` to insert at the end the list in `list::splice`.

Comment: @dyp but you must know the size of the list in advance, so you have first find a delim and then splice in properly sized list

Comment: You can splice individual elements, and I think that's the key here.

Comment: do you think this have significant advantage in this case?

Comment: Yes, because a `std::list` allocates for each new element IIRC (and with splicing, you get rid of that allocation).

Comment: You can also avoid this copy: `elems.push_back( l);` and the associated allocations either with another splice or with a swap (see Yakk's solution).

Comment: even better: while ( it != v.end() && *it < delim) { ++it; } and splice a range

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Splicing a range to another list has linear complexity, since `std::list::size` is required to have constant complexity (in C++11, and in C++03, many StdLib implementations give that guarantee).

Comment: yes, true, so I will leave these examples as just few ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

//...

auto first = YourList.begin();

while ( first != YourList.end() )
{
   auto last = std::find_if( first, YourList.end(), std::bind2nd( std::greater<int>(), 500 ) );
   if ( last != YourList.end() ) ++last;

   YourVector.push_back( std::list<int>( first, last ) );

   first = last;
}
```

Comment: Note that `bind2nd` is deprecated in C++11 (the OP doesn't use the C++11 tag, though).

Comment: You can also splice the list; this could be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through the numbers and get the distance between the locations where you need to split the list.
2. Use the splice function in List for each split location:

   ```
   lst.splice( newLst.begin(), newLst, lst.begin(), lst.begin() + sliceLength);
   ```

   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/

(Note that splice will destroy the original list)

Comment: `lst.begin() + sliceLength` will probably not work since a list iterator is not a RandomAccessIterator. Even if it works, this can trivially be optimized by *not* iterating `sliceLength` steps again.

Comment: The list iterator is indeed a BidirectionalIterator. It does not have support for addition. You learn something everyday. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/